# Splash screen problems with 13.04

Tags: boot, 13.04, plymouth, logo

I am having a cosmetic issue with Ubuntu 13.04. After a fresh install the splash screen was fine and I had restart the laptop several times while attempting to install my wireless drivers. After everything was installed correctly, it was still fine. I ran Software Updater and needed to restart, so on next boot-up this is now what the boot screen looks like. Both start up and shutdown are affected and both are shown in the video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN0zZC5YJFc
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Also wanted to say, I tried `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! In a terminal, I typed: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Next, I went to the end of the document and typed this: `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1440x900`

1440x900 being my native resolution for my screen. Yours may vary. Check your monitor settings. After saving and closing the file, I typed in `sudo update-grub` and voila! My boot screen was back to normal. 

 It has something to do with Nvidia chips and wanting to put the terminal in a low resolution mode.